# Showing that an upper sum is an upper bound of the improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The question states to show that for $N = 1,2,3,...$ we have:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k} \color{green}> \frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{2N + 1}{3}}$$

My idea is to show the following

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k} \color{red}{\geq} \int_{0}^{N} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}$$

$$\left.\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k} \color{red}{\geq} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}x - x^2}{2} + \frac{\ln{(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x})}{2} \right|_{0}^{N} = \frac{\sqrt{N^2+1}N - N^2}{2} + \frac{\ln{(\sqrt{N^2+1}+N})}{2}$$

Notice the strict inequality in the first inequality and then in the last inequality we can remove the first term on the RHS to have only the logarithm as follows.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k} \color{green}> \frac{\ln{(\sqrt{N^2+1}+N})}{2} \color{green}> \frac{\ln{(\sqrt{2N^2+1}})}{2} \color{green}> \frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{2N + 1}{3}}$$ $\blacksquare$

Now my concern is that can I do it any simpler way than having to compute that horror of an integral? Thank you for any insights!

Comment: Unfortunately, we actually have $$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k}<\int_{0}^{N} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}$$ because $x\mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}$ is decreasing.

Comment: @SangchulLee oh my, you're right, I over-looked that..

Comment: The integral is quite simple


$$k=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\quad \implies \quad I=\int \frac{dt}{(t-1) (t+1)^2}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{4} \log \left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)-\frac{1}{2 (t+1)}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Any advice on how you noticed such substitution? Or just similar integral practice? :)

Comment: @TeodorasPaura. Unfortunately for me, 65 years of practice ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k}
&\geq \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{(k+1)+k}
\geq \int_{1}^{N} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2x+1}
= \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{2N+1}{3}\right).
\end{align*}

In the second step, we used the following general observation:

> **Observation.** Let $f : [n, n+1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be non-increasing. Then
>
> $$ f(n) = \int_{n}^{n+1} f(n) \, \mathrm{d}x \geq \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Comment: Shouldn't the upper bound of the integral be $N+1$ ?

Comment: @TeodorasPaura That is also correct, but reducing the upper bound from $N+1$ to $N$ only makes the integral smaller (because the integrand is non-negative).

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I should be more careful with the bounds. :)